# Keep update window open after update complete with AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

[I know that there is already a post about this question](http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-ankhsvn-general/suggestions/98246-keep-update-window-open-after-update-complete) but I wonder if a solution or workaround exists to resolve this problem.

Each time I update my source code, a window of AnkhSVN is displayed but I like to review which files have been updated but if the window is closed after the process, the only other solution that I have is to show the log of my project with TortoiseSVN in the windows explorer.

Another solution would be to update with tortoise svn instead of the AnkhSVN but I prefer to be able to stay in Visual Studio.

I can also use VisualSvn that is built closely with TortoiseSVN but I prefer to use AnkhSVN.

Anyone have a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Look in the "output window", and select AnkhSVN. The same output that goes to the dialog is logged there.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification to Sander Rijken's answer, select the dropdown titled "Show output from" in your output window. It's at the top.

Comment: I should have put this as a comment under Sander's answer. Please don't upvote.